# how can i add routes asynchronously to iron router?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, iron-router

i have a meteor method in `lib/server/plugins.js`

```
Meteor.methods({
  getPlugins: function() {
    return [
      { path: 'test' },
      { path: 'test2' }
    ]
  }
});
```

and my router config file in `lib/routes.js`

```
Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('home');
}); 

Meteor.call('getPlugins', function(e,r) {
    if(!e) {
        for(var plugin in r) {
            function() {
                this.route(r[plugin].name);
            })
        }
    } else {
        console.log(e);
    }
})

var routes  = [
    { path: '/test3' },
    { path: '/test4' }
]

for(var i in routes) {
    Router.map(function() {
        this.route(routes[i].path);
    });
}
```

all the routes in the local variable routes works fine, but the routes that come from `getPlugins` iron router say `Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:3000/test2."`

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you decided not to use a `/plugins/:pluginId` general route instead of multiple small ones? As far as I know, Iron-Router is more designed to be a one-time configuration...

Comment: each path have its own template

Comment: Well, you could still make it work correctly without the need to add more routes. It would be the subject of another question then.

Comment: i feel a bit enlightened, let me search what i can find, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first add a / before routes:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getPlugins: function() {
    return [
      { path: '/test' },
      { path: '/test2' }
    ]
  }
});
```

Then modify this `this.route(r[plugin].name);` to `Router.route(r[plugin].path)`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Kyll i came up with this solution, it does the job, but i still have questions about sub paths

```
Router.route('/:plugin', function() {
    var that = this;
    Meteor.call('getPlugins', function(e,r) {
        if(!e) {
            for(var plugin in r) {       
                if(r[plugin].path == that.params.plugin) {
                    that.render(that.params.plugin);
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log(e);
        }
    })
});
```